# merge and sql join different results sas to bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, sas

sas transcription for bigquery

```
data mydata;
  infile datalines;
  input list $ NDC discount;
datalines;
Nov 11 50
Dec 12 20
Nov 11 50
May 12 .
Mar 11 30
;
run;

data mydata2;
  infile datalines;
  input list $ NDC discount;
datalines;
Jan 11 40
Dec 12 20
Mar 10 50
May 12 .
Mar 11 30
;
run;

proc sql;
  create table x1 as
  select *
  from mydata t1 left join mydata2 t2 on(t1.list=t2.list);
quit;

proc sort data=mydata;
  by list;
run;

proc sort data=mydata2;
  by list;
run;

data x2;
  merge mydata(in=t1) mydata2;
  by list;
  if t1;
run;
```

I hope the results are the same. I'm trying in many ways via sql to solve my problems, with COEALESCE functions and others. Helpe me!

Results X1:
[image]

Results X2:
[image]

Comment: You should not be doing a data step merge with common non-by variables when the by variables do not uniquely identify the  observations in both datasets.  Why do you want to replicate the mistake into BIGQUERY?

Comment: This part of documentation (https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/n1i8w2bwu1fn5kn1gpxj18xttbb0.htm#p1rfsa0978il4yn1q7s3rknmzfyr) clearly states: "*The MERGE statement does not produce a Cartesian product on a many-to-many match-merge. Instead, it performs a one-to-one merge while there are observations in the BY group in at least one data set. When all observations in the BY group have been read from one data set and there are still more observations in another data set, SAS performs a one-to-many merge until all BY group observations have been read.*"

Comment: Good reading about how merge really works is this article: https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug99/ad/ad155.pdf